# Google Apps Script getting information from google directory

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been tasked with creating an apps script for google forms that when submitted will send an email with the responses to several people. The form is for bonus recommendation so it will need to go to HR, the executive team, and the employees manager. I have the script working to where it will email the requested HR and the executive team but not the manager. HR and executive was simple because those are static teams, but the manager will change depending on the employee. I have the script where it will get the get the name of the employee and store it in the variable employeeName. I see that apps script has the admin directory service that I should be able to pull from the I am struggling to make it work the way I need. Below is the script so far.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var responses = e.namedValues;
 var htmlBody = '<ol>';
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('redacted');
 var gSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
 var lastRow = gSheet.getLastRow();
 var range = gSheet.getRange(lastRow,3);
 var employeeName = range.getValue();

 for (Key in responses) {
   var header = Key;
   var data = responses[Key];
   htmlBody += '<li>' + header + ': ' + data  + '</li>';
 };
 htmlBody += '</ol>';
 GmailApp.sendEmail('redacted', 'Bonus Recommendation', '', {htmlBody:htmlBody})

}
```

I feel like I am missing something super simple. I should also add that I am NOT a scripter or programmer by any stretch. I'm just the net admin who drew the short straw for this project. (It does seem that I will be learning javascript so I can use apps script better).

Comment: You are currently retrieving `employeeName` from you spreadsheet? If that's the case, why do you want to call the Directory service? What information do you want to retrieve from there? (btw I assume you are a domain admin? You need to be if you want to call this service).

Answer (score 0):

Each namedValues is a array so try this:

responses[Key][0];

The reason they do that is because if you reuse the same form repeated the form continues to add new columns for different questions and you can end up with the same name in two different columns.

Personally, I would have used e.values.